# Magento 2 : Display log file information in an admin grid

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent, log

Right now I'am logging a lot of informations about my webservices (duration , status , errorMessage)

And I want to display it in a grid Ui-component like , in an admin tab I already created.

How can I use something like the grid Ui-component to display my log info ?

Maybe it's not the best way to do it and you can help with another idea !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Magento 2 module for disaply log file in admin panel grid - https://github.com/metasyncSite/Magento-2-log-viewer